# Using the 64 bit postgresql odbc drivers

Tags: sql, postgresql, odbc

How do I reference and use the 64 bit postgresql odbc drivers. what is the dsn less connection string for the 64 bit driver. I Do not want to use the 32 bit drivers AT ALL! . I am running windows 7 and access 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

1. install 64 bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver. Such drivers have `-x64` in their names, example: `psqlodbc_09_03_0100-x64.zip`.
2. To test if it is working use 64 bit `odbcad32.exe` to create DSN and test it with "Test" button
3. If DSN works well then you can try to use DSN less connection string.

Use something like:

```
Driver={PostgreSQL 64-Bit ODBC Drivers};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=dbname;Uid=name;Pwd=password;
```